# I am trying to run a task schedule on cPanel but not working

Tags: laravel

I am trying to run cron job on the daily bases at 16:00 but unfortunately not working please help me thanks

Note :- when i select schedule ->everMinute() it works perfectly.

**/home3/urbanhq6/public_html/new/app/Console/Kernel.php**

```
 /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('reminder:email')
             ->dailyAt('16:00');
    }
```

**cron job timing set**

```
Minute  Hour    Day  Month  Weekday 
0   16  *        *    *
```

Comment: Your cron job timing in cPanel should be set to `* * * * *`. Laravel handles it past there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should adjust your cPanel cron to run every minute, with timings of `* * * * *`. Laravel handles its own scheduling via rules (like `->dailyAt('16:00')`) in the `Kernel.php` file; running every minute lets Laravel do that without needing adjustments when you add a new command to the schedule.

Now, running at `0 16 * * *` *should* still work for this particular set of rules. The likely answer is your server and your Laravel are on different timezones - check the timezone on the server with `date`, and check `config/app.php`'s `timezone` value.

If there's a mismatch, your cron is running at 16:00 server time, but Laravel is adjusting the time to its own timezone, which means the two don't match. Switching your cron to `* * * * *` will fix this - the cron will start running (as it does with `everyMinute()`) - but the task *will run at an unexpected hour*.